# Traversing a linked list with a structure inside

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

So I a linked list of 4 students and inside each node for the linked list is a structure that holds some data about the students. I want to traverse this linked list and print the data inside each of the structures. I can traverse the linked list expect all the data print is 0. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void displayGrades( struct Outer *O);
void calculateGrades(struct Outer *O);
void readGrades( struct Outer *O);

struct Inner{   
int id;
string name;
    double midterm1;
    double midterm2;
    double midtermTotal;
    double lab_H;
    double finalExam;
    double total;   
};  
Inner i1;

struct Outer{
Inner  data;
Outer *next;
};  
struct Outer o1, o2, o3, o4;

int main()
{

 readGrades(&o1);
 calculateGrades(&o1);
 displayGrades(&o1);
 //o1.next = &o2;
 /*
 readGrades(&o2);
 calculateGrades(&o2);
 displayGrades(&o2);
 //o2.next =&o3;

 readGrades(&o3);
 calculateGrades(&o3);
 displayGrades(&o3);
 //o3.next =&o4;

 readGrades(&o4);
 calculateGrades(&o4);
 displayGrades(&o4);
 //o4.next =NULL;
 */


Outer *ptro1;
ptro1 = new Outer;
Outer *ptro2;
ptro2 = new Outer;
Outer *ptro3;
ptro3 = new Outer;
Outer *ptro4;
ptro4 = new Outer;
Outer *head=ptro1;

ptro1->next = ptro2;
ptro2->next = ptro3;
ptro3->next = ptro4;
ptro4->next = NULL;

while(head!=NULL) // && i<=2)
{
  cout<<"Student ID: "<<head->data.id<<endl;
  cout<<"Student Midterm1: "<<head->data.midterm1<<endl;
  cout<<"Student Midterm2: "<<head->data.midterm2<<endl;
  cout<<"Student Labs and Homework: "<<head->data.lab_H<<endl;
  cout<<"Student Final Exam: "<<head->data.finalExam<<endl;
  head = head->next;
}
return 0;


}

void readGrades(struct Outer *O){

cout<<"Enter the student's id: "<<endl;     
cin>>o1.data.id;
cout<<"Enter the student's midterm #1 grade: ";     
cin>>o1.data.midterm1;
cout<<"Enter the student's midterm #2 grade: ";     
cin>>o1.data.midterm2;
cout<<"Enter the student's lab and homework grade: ";       
cin>>o1.data.lab_H;
cout<<"Enter the student's final exam grade: ";     
cin>>o1.data.finalExam;
}

void displayGrades(struct Outer *O){    

cout<<"The students final grade is: ";

if(O->data.total>=90)
    {   
    cout<<"A"<<endl;
    }
else if(O->data.total<=89 && O->data.total>=80)
    {   
    cout<<"B"<<endl;
    }
else if(O->data.total<=79 && O->data.total>=70)
    {   
    cout<<"C"<<endl;
    }
else if(O->data.total<=69 && O->data.total<60)
    {
    cout<<"F"<<endl;
    }
}

    void calculateGrades(struct Outer *O){
     O->data.midtermTotal=(((O->data.midterm1/50)+(O- >data.midterm2/50))/2)*35;
     O->data.lab_H=(O->data.lab_H/20)*25;
     O->data.finalExam=(O->data.finalExam/100)*40;
     O->data.total=O->data.midtermTotal+O->data.lab_H+O->data.finalExam;
    //displayGrades();
}
```

Comment: So you're saving your data to o1 ... o4, then making a brand new set of structs ptro1...ptro4 and reading data from that, and you're confusing as to why they're empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below function you need to use O as you are passing it but you are using
o1 which will overwrite every time

```
void readGrades(struct Outer *O)
{
cout<<"Enter the student's id: "<<endl;     
cin>>O->data.id;
cout<<"Enter the student's midterm #1 grade: ";     
cin>>O->data.midterm1;
cout<<"Enter the student's midterm #2 grade: ";     
cin>>O->data.midterm2;
cout<<"Enter the student's lab and homework grade: ";       
cin>>O->data.lab_H;
cout<<"Enter the student's final exam grade: ";     
cin>>O->data.finalExam;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create a constructor that initializes the member variables to 0. Most of compilers do not do that by default.

```
struct Inner{ 

Inner() : id(0),midterm1(0),midtermTotal(0), lab_H(0), finalExam(0),   total(0)
{
}

int id;
string name;
    double midterm1;
    double midterm2;
    double midtermTotal;
    double lab_H;
    double finalExam;
   double total;
```

};

Comment: This does not answer the question and should be a comment.

Comment: I believe he expects 0 in the values that are not being set, instead he is getting garbage. The output of this code in Visual C++ outputs 

....Student Labs and Homework: -6.27744e+66
Student Final Exam: -6.27744e+66
Student ID: -842150451...